# Rendering data in FlatList from firebase in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I am learning React Native. I have been using ListView but it is now removed so I need some help in code conversion of ListView to FlatList. I'm using firebase. Please help me in this.

EmployeeList.js:

```js
import _ from 'lodash';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { employeesFetch } from '../actions';
import ListItem from './ListItem';

class EmployeeList extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.employeesFetch();

        this.createDataSource(this.props);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        // nextProps are the next set of props that this component
        // will be rendered with
        // this.props is still the old set of props

        this.createDataSource(nextProps);
    }

    createDataSource({ employees }) {
        const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
            rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
        });

        this.dataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(employees);
    }

    renderRow(employee) {
        return <ListItem employee={employee} />;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ListView
                enableEmptySections
                dataSource={this.dataSource}
                renderRow={this.renderRow}
            />
        );
    }
}

const maptStateToProps = state => {
    const employees = _.map(state.employees, (val, uid) => {
        return { ...val, uid };
    });

    return { employees };
};

export default connect(maptStateToProps, { employeesFetch })(EmployeeList);
```

ListItem.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { CardSection } from './common'

class ListItem extends Component {
    render() {
        const { name } = this.props.item;

        return (
            <CardSection>
                <Text style={styles.titleStyle}>{name}</Text>
            </CardSection>
        );
    }
}

const styles = {
    titleStyle: {
        fontSize: 18,
        paddingLeft: 15
    }
};

export default ListItem;
```

Reducer of the List
EmployeeReducer.js

```
import { EMPLOYEES_FETCH_SUCCESS } from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case EMPLOYEES_FETCH_SUCCESS:
            return action.payload;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Action Creator of the list:
EmployeeActions.js:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import { EMPLOYEE_UPDATE, EMPLOYEE_CREATE, EMPLOYEES_FETCH_SUCCESS } from './types';

export const employeeUpdate = ({ prop, value }) => {
    return {
        type: EMPLOYEE_UPDATE,
        payload: { prop, value }
    };
};

export const employeeCreate = ({ name, phone, shift }) => {
    const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();

    return (dispatch) => {
        firebase.database().ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/employees`)
            .push({ name, phone, shift })
            .then(() => {
                dispatch({ type: EMPLOYEE_CREATE });
                Actions.pop();
            });
    };
};

export const employeesFetch = () => {
    const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();

    return (dispatch) => {
        firebase.database().ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/employees`)
            .on('value', snapshot => {
                dispatch({ type: EMPLOYEES_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: snapshot.val() });
            });
    }
};
```

Can you help me in rendering the data in FlatList?

Comment: what've you done so far

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just change:

```
<ListView
            enableEmptySections
            dataSource={this.dataSource}
            renderRow={this.renderRow}
        />
```

to

```
<FlatList
     data={this.dataSource}
     renderItem={this.renderRow}
/>
```

Comment: What about ```createDataSource({ employees })?